# Visual C++ Development

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-vista

I'm learning C++, and know a little bit of Visual Basic and an Delphi.

But I want to know, is there some program like Delphi, but for C++. Something where you can drag a button to a form, double click it, the like in Delphi and VB: opens a code editor and you edit the code of the button, but with a similar code of C++?

I'm using Windows Vista.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you use MFC within Visual Studio.

MFC is Visual Studio's C++ class library for writing Windows programs, and for an MFC form Visual Studio behaves exactly as you describe.

As of Visual Studio 2008 with [an upgrade pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D466226B-8DAB-445F-A7B4-448B326C48E7&displaylang=en) you can create Office 2007 style applications, and Visual Studio style applications, using MFC.

Comment: Isn't there another way to accomplish what the author is asking for avoiding the bloated MFC?

Comment: Good answer! MFC is strong in exactly that area; WYSIWYG dialog design and simple mapping between UI and code.

However, MFC code is not idiomatic C++ and if the OP is looking to learn C++ there's probably better libraries. I don't know how the others stack up -- eg QT and wxWidgets?

Comment: MFC is included in Visual C++ Express Edition?

Comment: @Nathan: Ah, no, MFC isn't included in Visual C++ Express Edition. I didn't know that was what you were using.

Comment: Technically speaking, you don't need an MFC project to use the dialog editor - it's available in plain Win32 apps too (it just edits dialogs in resource files in that case).

Comment: @Pavel: that's true, but you don't get that simple link between the resources and the code, "double-click to open the code editor".

Answer (score 4):

There used to be "C++ Builder", a C++ version of Delphi, I don't know if this product is still being developed or not.

UPDATE: to summarize information from the comments, C++ Builder is actively developed and the product page is http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/

Comment: It is,In fact,it will be in development.I'm waiting for CodeGear Weaver,which is meant to be Delphi & C++B 2010

Answer (score 1):

You can have the following IDEs with GUI designers for free;

- Visual Studio 2008 express from Microsoft
- Qt Creator from Nokia
- Eclipse with Qt plugin from community :)
- C++ Builder from Embarcadero
  (previously CodeGear, previously
  Borland)

**Have fun with C++!**

Answer (score 0):

There are other packages besides MFC that do GUI stuff, but I don't think they plug-in to Visual Studio.  I must confess, I have never been a fan of MFC.  I find it ugly and painful, so I can't really recommend it.

Qt has a designer, as does GTK.  I haven't used the Qt designer, but the GTK one works well. It can be found here: http://glade.gnome.org/  You can get glade for Windows here: http://gladewin32.sourceforge.net/

It can be hassle to set these up, though.

Honestly, while I like C++ a lot, writing GUIs for Windows is not where it excels.  I would recommend that you look at C# instead.  You can still interface with C++ if you need to, but it makes writing Windows GUIs *so* much nicer.